# Which was the first pressurized aircraft?

Tags: aviation-history, cabin-pressure

Which aircraft was the first one to fly pressurized?

[image]
<sup>High altitude breathing apparatus, 1918 ([source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySmdy.jpg))</sup>

I mean an aircraft which didn't require to don an oxygen mask above a certain altitude, excluding very high altitude where a mask is still required due to quick loss of consciousness after a depressurization event.

Answer (score 14):

The [history section of the cabin pressurization Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabin_pressurization#History) names a few based on the feat:

> The aircraft that pioneered pressurized cabin systems include:
>
> - Packard-Le Père LUSAC-11, (1920, a modified French design, not actually pressurized but with an enclosed, oxygen enriched cockpit)
> - Engineering Division USD-9A, a modified Airco DH.9A (1921 - the first aircraft to fly with the addition of a pressurized cockpit module)
> - Junkers Ju 49 (1931 - a German experimental aircraft purpose-built to test the concept of cabin pressurization)
> - Farman F.1000 (1932 - a French record breaking pressurized cockpit, experimental aircraft)
> - Chizhevski BOK-1 (1936 - a Russian experimental aircraft)
> - Lockheed XC-35 (1937 - an American pressurized aircraft. Rather than a pressure capsule enclosing the cockpit, the monocoque fuselage skin was the pressure vessel.)
> - Renard R.35 (1938 - the first pressurized piston airliner, which crashed on first flight)
> - Boeing 307 (1938 - the first pressurized airliner to enter commercial service)
> - Lockheed Constellation (1943 - the first pressurized airliner in wide service)
> - Avro Tudor (1946 - first British pressurized airliner)
> - de Havilland Comet (British, Comet 1 1949 - the first jetliner, Comet 4 1958 - resolving the Comet 1 problems)
> - Tupolev Tu-144 and Concorde (1968 USSR and 1969 Anglo-French respectively - first to operate at very high altitude)
> - SyberJet SJ30 (2005) First civilian business jet to certify 12.0 psi pressurization system allowing for a sea level cabin at 41,000 ft (12,000 m).

If it is the whole plane and not just the cockpit, then we're looking at the **[Lockheed XC-35](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_XC-35),** or the **[Junkers Ju 49](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junkers_Ju_49)** (whose purpose was to investigate the techniques of cabin pressurization).

For the first in service, then it's the **[Boeing 307 Stratoliner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_307_Stratoliner).**

[image]

[image]
XC-35 (top) and the modified enclosed cockpit of the [USD-9A](https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4043/4564651520_5b96d81cfd_z.jpg).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70869/discussion-on-answer-by-ymb1-which-was-the-first-pressurized-aircraft).